# Input type submit won't trigger when it's clicked

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, import-from-excel

I have trouble with my code, I want to create an upload button to upload my .xlsx file, but it won't trigger even when I try to click it.

My view.php :

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url("index.php/fin/cost_control/workingcanvas/import"); ?>" method="post" id="import_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label>Pilih File Excel</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required accept=".xls, .xlsx" /></p>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="import" name="import" value="Import" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>
```

My controller:

```
public function import(){
   include APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
   $excelreader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
   $loadexcel = $excelreader->load('excel/'.$this->filename.'.xlsx');
   $sheet = $loadexcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true ,true);
   $numrow = 1;
   foreach($sheet as $row){
     if($numrow > 1){
       array_push($data, array(
         'nis'=>$row['A'],
         'nama'=>$row['B'],
         'jenis_kelamin'=>$row['C'],
         'alamat'=>$row['D'],
       ));
     }
     $numrow++;
    }
  $this->SiswaModel->insert_multiple($data);
  redirect("Siswa");
}
```

and my model:

```
public function insert_multiple($data){
   $this->db->insert_batch('siswa', $data);
}
```

I've tried with adding some part on autoload such as

> $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','file');

Any suggestions or advice? Thanks.

Comment: did you check your log? Is your Controller is in a nested folder?

Comment: `it won't trigger even when I try to click it` - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

first load form helper in autoload file of codeigniter or load manually

```php
$autoload['helper'] = array('url'); // autoload
$this->load->helper->('form'); // manually loading form helper
```

you better use this

```php
$attributes = array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data');
echo form_open('index.php/fin/cost_control/workingcanvas/import', $attributes);

<your upload form code>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

instead of  tags

more info: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html